# FLV thumbnails

Tags: .net, flash

I'm looking for a .NET library or command line tool that would allow me to extract thumbnails from FLV files (AVI would be nice too, but not required). Something that would allow me to extract a frame maybe 15% into the movie would suffice. If it could extract a few frames, let's say one frame per minute, and make an animated GIF out of those frames it would be even cooler. Doesn't have to be open source, but it has to be something I can incorporate into my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg.exe -i video.flv -an -ss 00:00:03 -an -r 1 -vframes 1 -y %d.jpg
```

(Save a single frame at position 3 seconds during the video as a jpeg)